# How can i get all the deleted or updated lines in a trigger oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

How can i get all the affected row in the trigger.

In sybase there is a table "deleted" which stores copies of the affected rows during delete and update statements

[sybase documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.sqlug/html/sqlug/sqlug813.htm)

Is there any solution in oracle which do the same in a table level trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `new` and `old` values in the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
  BEFORE DELETE OR UPDATE ON table_name
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN    
    dbms_output.put('Old: ' || :old.column);
    dbms_output.put('New: ' || :new.column);
END;
/
```

It's not the same like in sybase, but it is what are you looking for.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg13trg.htm) you can find more information.

Comment: In this case my problem is the :old and :new only contain the currently inserted or deleted valu not the collection of all affected. i gues i need a table level trigger not a for each row trigger.

Comment: Why do you need all rows in the same time?

Comment: Becouse if i run the query like `update table t something=somethingelse where t.id = :new.id` for each row and i update >1000 row the trigger runs >1000 time and run this query as well. but if i can use something like this `update table t something=somethingelse where t.id in (select n.id from new n)` which will run onley once It will run faster.

Comment: You can't do that in oracle like in sybase. Maybe you have to save `new.id` in another table, and use it the table in your `in ()` clause.

Comment: current it work like that. But i wanted to change this behavier. But i won't... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no analogue to the "deleted" table that I know of in Oracle.

Depending on what it is that you need to do, you can use a [compound trigger](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/trigger-enhancements-11gr1.php#compound_triggers) to accomplish set based actions on the rows affected by the statement, as described at in Tim Hall's [oracle-base site](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/database-triggers-overview.php#compound). Using this approach, you can define row-level triggers that accumulate (for example) a value or count, store it in the global part of the trigger, and access those values in the AFTER INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE sections in the trigger.  The globals remain defined for the entire duration of all of the trigger points.

When triggers get this complex, however, I'm less of a fan of trigger-based solutions than putting the code in application packages/procedures/functions.